# OpenGL eye position to texture space

Tags: opengl, textures, volume-rendering, raymarching

I'm following [this tutorial by nVidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-v-physics-simulation/chapter-30-real-time-simulation-and-rendering-3d-fluids) for implementing a fluid simulation, however i'm confused about this part in the the ray marching algorithm section.

> The ray direction is given by the vector from the eye to the entry point (both in texture space).

I already have the coordinates for the ray entry points so that's not an issue, but i don't understand how can i get the eye position in texture space.